# Create Rank in Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create Rank in spreadsheet using google apps script instead of formula array. How can I achive what I want.The green color is what I want to put the rank using google apps script.
[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you should follow the steps below:

1. Retrieve the values from the spreadsheet's `D` column

To do this, the following methods can be of help:

- `openById(id)` - returns the spreadsheet with the specified id;
- `getSheetByName(name)` - returns the sheet with the specified name;
- `getRange(2, 4, NO_ROWS, 1)` - returns the values from the `D` column; however, don't forget to specify the number of rows the `D` column has;
- `getValues()` - returns the values from the range; please take into account that this will end up returning a **two-dimensional array**.

2. Compare the values in order to find the largest value out of all of them.
3. After you end up getting the maximum value, you can simply color the cell background by using `setBackground('COLOR')`.

#### Reference

- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String));
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getSheetByName(String));
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues());
- [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setBackground(String)).